Roboflow device management. In which GPU is the model loaded?
I am experimenting with the SDK of Roboflow, I haven't found documentation on device management. I have three questions:

Is the model loaded to GPU by default?
What happens when multiple GPUs are available?
And how do I define in which GPU I want the model allocated?

EDIT:
Roboflow does not expose the device directly as Pytorch would:
rf = Roboflow(api_key="YOUR API KEY")
project = rf.workspace().project("license-plate-recognition-rxg4e")
model = project.version("4").model
model = model.to("cuda:4")
> AttributeError: 'ObjectDetectionModel' object has no attribute 'to'


The code snippet you posted uses roboflow-python package which provides HTTP client making calls to the Roboflow platform.
If you intend to use the models inside your app, please use https://github.com/roboflow/inference package. Here you may find getting-started docs: https://inference.roboflow.com/quickstart/run_a_model/
Device can be specified by env flag: CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES
